# Where super.(something) should be placed?

Tags: java, android, super

I was wondering where the `super.onPreExecute()` for example, should be placed?
or in other words, which is the correct code:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutHomeInfo);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    progress = new ProgressBar(mContext);
    parent.addView(progress, params);
}
```

or

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutHomeInfo);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    progress = new ProgressBar(mContext);
    parent.addView(progress, params);
    super.onPreExecute();
}
```

Comment: I suspect you implement `AsyncTask` and the super methods you call here are empty and it does not matter where or if you call them. I'd simply remove the line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wherever you want.

Neither are wrong, it just all depends **when** you want to call the parent function, and *that* is all up to **you** (the developer).

Comment: The exception being with constructors, where the `super` call must be made first.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas true, but that format is just `super(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `super class method`, where to place is dependent on functionality. For e.g. Suppose you are initializing some components(in your method) and rendering ui(super class) then you would intialize them in your method and then call super method which will render UI.